# sqlite records are not displaying for iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i can only show last elemnts out of 10 records

```
qlite3 *database;


scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sqlStatement = "select name,score from game";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {



                // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                //if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                        // Read the data from the result row


                 Book *  aBook = [[Book alloc] init];

                // NSString *id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                aBook.id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
aBook.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];


                       SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];






                [books addObject:aBook];
       //        aBook.name  shows all 10 names

                } 
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

now if i call this in table view like `cell.text=aBook.name` so it only display last element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop you are creating a new array for appDelegate.books then inserting a book. This is why after the loop appDelegate.books only contains the last element.

Create the appDelegate and appDelegate.books only once before the loop instead.

**In Response**
Most likely you are setting each cell's text to the SAME book.

You said you used 'cell.text=aBook.name'.

How are you getting 'aBook.name'. You will need to use the indexPath like

```
Book* aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: hey i did as you said but now i can see all 10 records of same name plz help
i did this before while loop Book *  aBook = [[Book alloc] init];
  SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: perfect u saved my life hats of to ur knowledge :-)